# How can I get the first element of an NSMutablearray without crashing?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I can get the last element from an NSMutableArray with "lastObject". If the array was not initialized, it will return nil. Is there a similiar method or way to get this effect for the first object? This would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
id myFirstObject = myArray.count>0 ? myArray[0] : nil;
```

If you particularly want this to be part of an array, make it a category :

```
@interface NSArray (firstObject)
- (id)firstObject;
@end


@implementation NSArray (firstObject)
- (id)firstObject {
    return myArray.count>0 ? myArray[0] : nil;
}
@end
```

Then you get a firstObject that behaves the same as lastObject.

Answer (score 9):

New update in ios 7

```
 NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3];

 NSLog(@"First Object: %@", [array firstObject]); // 1
 NSLog(@"Last Object: %@", [array lastObject]); // 3
```

Comment: it's new with Xcode 5, not iOS7. It will work with iOS4+

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
    id x = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```